# nargs='?' does not work when two pos-arguments are split by one opt-argument, why?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using python 3.5.4(same with 3.7.0), and I have such a problem.

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('pos1')
argparser.add_argument('-a')
argparser.add_argument('pos2', nargs='?', default=2) # I'd like it optional
```

It works with first 3 cases but the 4th failed, why?

```
>>> argparser.parse_args(['-a', 'vala', '10', '20'])
Namespace(a='vala', pos1='10', pos2='20')
>>>
>>> argparser.parse_args(['-a', 'vala', '10'])
Namespace(a='vala', pos1='10', pos2=2)
>>>
>>> argparser.parse_args(['100', '-a', 'vala'])
Namespace(a='vala', pos1='100', pos2=2)
>>> 
>>> argparser.parse_args(['100', '-a', 'vala', '200'])
usage: [-h] [-a A] pos1 [pos2]
: error: unrecognized arguments: 200
```

For the 4th case, I think `pos2` should receive `200`. How should I make it work without breaking the former three?

Comment: I guess the problen is that `pos2` is the positional argument. In the 4th case it's not the second position.

Comment: This seems like a bug, you should submit it. In the meanwhile, if you must support this you may have to parse yourself the command line.

Comment: It's a known issue without an easy fix. The ? argument gets filled (by nothing) when `pos1` is parsed. I've explained this in more detail in previous SO questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50916124/901925

Comment: I added to the duplicate a fix that uses the new (3.7) `parse_intermixed_args` method.

Comment: Another fix, change `pos2` to `--pos2`.  Traditionally positionals were required, and optionals not.  The `nargs='?'` now creates a non-required `positional`, which may be convenient, except when it isn't.  Look at how it's grouped in the `help`!

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj , `parse_known_args` should be a better workaround for my case for pre-3.7 python.

Answer (score 1):

I think `nargs='?'` uses some of the same machinery as `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` to consume otherwise-unused tokens.  It is known that `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` prevents the use of other positional arguments prior to regular option flags (with hyphens): [argparse.REMAINDER changes the behavior of positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280715/argparse-remainder-changes-the-behavior-of-positional-arguments)

It seems what's going on is that `argparse` can parse option flags after positional arguments only if all of those positional arguments are required.  Arguably a bug, but then again the classic Unix convention was to require all option flags (with hyphens) to come before all positional arguments.